# simple_form params hash including blank member?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Why is simple_form always generating a extra blank parameter? This is my code:

`<%= f.association :paragraph_titles, as: :check_boxes %>`

The params hash returns the checked title_id's PLUS an extra empty member:

`"paragraph_title_ids"=>["1","3","5","6",""],`

Where does that empty "" come from? How can I avoid it? It also happens if I check all possible titles? thnx in advance ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually its an rails issue.

Please check this issue from Rails this will help you https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5402

and, You can be able to disable it in Rails 4.

Check issue from `simple_form` at below link

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/603